# php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known,why is this showing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp, connectivity

```php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost ","root "," ","project");//connectivity
```

This is code, I am getting the error:

> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Comment: `No such host` means `localhost ` didn't resolve.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your code

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost ","root "," ","project");//connectivity
```

change it to this

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","project");//connectivity
```

Do not use spaces.